# Azure document DB orderby timestamp field

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a `timestamp` field in my each document. the timestamp is in `ISODate` format. Is there any way i can sort the data using it in Document Explorer or Query Explorer?

Answer (score 17):

Each document has a default timestamp field named '_ts'.
You can for instance get last documents with the following query:

`SELECT * FROM c ORDER BY c._ts DESC`

Comment: will it work with my own timestamp and not the document's build-in `_ts` field?

Comment: Are you sure? because I'll be storing the timestamp as a `string` in `ISODate` format. This is because their sdk didn't let me use the js `Date` object directly when I posted this question

Answer (score 1):

If you have a full precision (-1) index on your ISO date string field ORDER BY works as expected.

Comment: uhh sorry i didnt get what you said. can you elaborate it?

Comment: You have to specify an indexing policy the uses all of the data in value. Without it, DocumentDB will only use the first 3 bytes. You want to specify a range index.

Answer (score 0):

Store the date as an epoch, not ISO date. If you need a humanly readable date in the document, you can store both.

See this one https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/working-with-dates-in-azure-documentdb-4/

-
As per comment, and Larry's answer, you can use Range indexing with precision -1 (a requirement for range indexing). You can set your index requirements from the portal as json or by code.

```
new IncludedPath { 
    Path = "/your_iso_property_path" ,
    Indexes = new Collection<Index> {
        new RangeIndex(DataType.String) { Precision = -1 } 
    }
});
```

For further details, see https://azure.microsoft.com/nb-no/documentation/articles/documentdb-indexing-policies/

If you created the collection using the API or some time ago using the portal the default indexing for strings will be hash indexing.

Comment: That's an option and it is more space efficient but I have found using ISO date strings to be as performant. It is human readable and I don't have to add a demoralization ("store both")  like you suggest.